# add an admin user for a specific database only in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

On Mongodb 2.6.4 I want to create an admin user for a specific database.

I tried this:

```
use myapp-dev
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myapp-dev-admin",
    pwd: "xxx",
    roles:
    [
      {
        role: "userAdmin",
        db: "myapp-dev"
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

It appeared to create the user, and I could auth with `db.auth('myapp-dev-admin', 'xxxx')`

Except he can't do anything on the db.

```
> show dbs
 2014-10-30T02:11:51.376-0700 listDatabases failed:{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0 }",
"code" : 13
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
> show collections
 2014-10-30T02:12:02.672-0700 error: {
"$err" : "not authorized for query on myapp-dev.system.namespaces",
"code" : 13
 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:131
```

Comment: Give more permissions - you have just given user administration privileges, which aren't sufficient to read or write from the actual collections.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this......

```
use mydb
db.createUser({user: 'mydbadmin', pwd: 'xxx', roles: ["dbOwner"]})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hope it helps...

```
db.createUser({
  "user": "username",
  "pwd": passwordPrompt(),
  "roles": [
    "readWrite",
    "dbAdmin"
  ]
})
```